# hadoop user file permissions

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hdfs, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

i have a problem in setting hadoop file permissions in hortonworks and cloudera.

My requirement is:

```
1. create a new user with new group  
2. create user directory in hdfs ( ex. /user/myuser )  
3. Now this folder ( in this case /user/myuser ) must be accessible to only user and its group but not other users and other groups.
```

Following commands are used by me. ( in centos 6)

1.create group >>> `groupadd mygroup`
2. create new user who belongs to new group  >>>>  `useradd -g mygroup myuser`
3. create user directory in hdfs  >>> `hadoop fs -mkdir /user/myuser`
4. changing ownership of the folder >>> `hadoop fs -chown -R myuser:mygroup /user/myuser`
5. giving permissions to user folder >>> `hadoop fs -chmod -R 700 /user/myuser`
6. i also changed the /tmp file permission to sticky bit. >>> `hadoop fs -chmod -R 1777 /tmp`

Here the problem comes, even setting this permissions the other users in other groups are accessing my data. please tell me the solution for this. I turned on hdfs file permissions by setting ( dfs.permission.enabled=true ).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you set the wrong property to enable permissions. You need to set the following property in hdfs-site:

```
dfs.permissions.enabled = true
```

This is a good resource for [HDFS permissions](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html)

Comment: sorry, its actually dfs.permissions.enabled=true not hadoop.permissions.enabled=true. still not getting answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should repeat your step on the master node (active namenode).

After that, run

```
hdfs dfsadmin -refreshUserToGroupsMappings
```