# Still cannot configure Cloudera Hadoop Security Now its kinit and principal

Tags: security, kerberos, cloudera

I am still stuck with cloudera security. I followed all step and configure  security including installing Kerberos. At end i created hdfs user in Kerberos using kadmin. i can do kinit hdfs and verified that there is ticket. My cluster is running in Cloudera quick start VM.

then i issue  **hdfs dfs -ls /**  command and i gave me errors

```
16/07/12 02:18:50 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
ls: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]; Host Details : local host is: "quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "quickstart.cloudera":8020;
```

I search internet and came across this post  **http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/cdh/3-x/3u6/CDH3-Security-Guide/cdh3sg_topic_14_2.html** which indicate some problems with Kerbrose. it says first create ticket using **kinit hdfs** and then renew ticket using **kinit -R**  but NOW this command is also giving error **kinit: Ticket expired while renewing credentials**. I again searched internet and found this link  **https://blog.godatadriven.com/kerberos_kdc_install.html** which indicate to modify principal's **maxrenewlife** setting that i did and verified. but still kinit -R giving the same error.

Note the OS CentOS on Cloudera QuickStart.    Stuck on this point of setting security for last 1 week so a help will be my life saver.

Regards
Shahzad Aslam

Comment: After `kinit`, run a `klist` to check what are the actual "lifetime" (usually 10h) and "renewable lifetime" (usually 7 days) of your ticket. If you are under "lifetime" then you can renew without a password (`kinit -R`) to get another "lifetime" -- until you finally hit "renewable lifetime".

Comment: Note that the actual "lifetime" is MIN(client setting, KDC setting) so check your KDC configuration...

Comment: While reviewing the klist for current principal (hdfs)    i notice that renew until is exactly same when ticket was issued. So that means i cannot renew. in kdc5.conf the renew_lifetime is 7d and ticket_lifetime is 24h.   is it relevant ?    Please suggest what setting should i configure ?

Comment: RTFM - http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.13/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html  >> `[libdefaults] renew_lifetime` Sets the default renewable lifetime for initial ticket requests. **The default value is 0**

Comment: Setting `ticket_lifetime = 86400`and `renew_lifetime = 604800` will enforce, on client side, the usual MAX values set on KDC side, i.e. 10h and 7d

Comment: I made changes in the krb5.conf, re-started Kerberos services and still the same behavior.   Shahzad

Comment: Things are getting stranger for me now.  I review this post **http://superuser.com/questions/1052153/kerberos-ticket-not-renewable** it says to renew a ticket i need to the command **modprinc -maxlife 1days -maxrenewlife 7days +allow_renewable Krbtgt/MYREALM.COM@MYREALM.COM **   notice krbtgt in principal instead of my hdfs user.   initially i was issuing the same command with hdfs@MYREALM.COM that does not have any effect.     now i can see ticket renew change        Kinit -R  has no errors  but still i cannot access the secure hadoop

Comment: `krbtgt/REALM@REALM` is the code name for the Kerberos authentication service itself (i.e the KDC), so modifying this "principal" means modifying system-level settings.

Comment: To enable detailed Kerberos traces, cf. https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/secrets.html -- see also the "errors" and "terrors" chapters about typical errors messages.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a guide to troubleshooting Kerberized CDH at [Running any Hadoop command fails after enabling security.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721304/running-any-hadoop-command-fails-after-enabling-security/39707462#39707462) .  Same content posted at http://sarastreeter.com/2016/09/26/resolving-hadoop-problems-on-kerberized-cdh-5-x/